# Cannot delete the mogolab service or the app with the message 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ibm-cloud, mlab

I tried to delete an old app bound with a mongolab service which is out of service. I can neither delete the app nor the mongolab service because the endpoint of the mongolab doesn't exist anymore. Do IBM Cloud or Bluemix people have a solution to this?

```
An error (10001) occurred while deleting the service.

Description:

Service instance MongoLab-NF: Service broker error: {"description"=>"TRANSPORT_ERROR - Received error with message \"401 Unauthorized\" while calling integration endpoint https://api.mongolab.com/api/appdirect/1/partners/IbmCloud/events?eventUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fbluemix.marketplace.ibmcloud.com%2Fapi%2Fintegration%2Fv1%2Fevents%2F4a1b66dd-531d-43e6-966d-0939fade9fa5 (1272 / MongoLab). Received response:\n"}
```

Comment: Hi, mLab support can help you with this. Can you please email into support@mlab.com? We'd be happy to help.

Comment: @tfogo I don't think so, it was a service removed from Bluemix(now IBM Cloud), from the message you can see IBM redirects the call to the partner service mongoLab and IBM should be able to remove the service from my dashboard even if 401 is returned from the endpoint (mongoLab) because the service doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Visit [IBM Cloud Support](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/support) and open a support ticket.

We users can't do much about it. Even, it won't allow deletion of app/service.

Once, the same is removed, bind new mLab service to your app.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a ticket at IBM Cloud Support, and we'll see what happens.